# Complex navigation, view stack in Android

Tags: android, view, stack

Could someone please point me to the right direction in terms of managing complex navigation flow in Android application.
**The use case is as follows**: User may click on a thumbnail in a grid of thumbnails, this takes user to "detailed" view of an image. This detailed view in addition to details of particular image has list/carousel  of "related" images to the image. User clicks on one of related and taken to "detailed" view of that image. And so on and so on. 
This basically creates a stack of unlimited/unknown length. 
By hitting "back" button user is taken to previous view. 
**The task**: I want to be able to set some limit to the views stack. So for example if user has navigated to 10-th "detailed" view - they will have to hit "back" only 3 times to get to grid of thumbnails where they have started the whole flow.
I am using fragments in my application.
Would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use 2 activities.  One activity shows the grid, the other the detailed view.  The detailed view maintains a stack of previous images, with max length 3.  When a related image is pressed, you push the current image onto the stack , dropping the oldest if needed.  Then redisplay for the new image.  Override onBackPressed to pop the image from the stack.  If the stack is empty, call finish() and you'll return to the grid.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion i would say is not Open a new Activity for "detailed" view .Instead just refresh the activity with the new supporting data.This way there would be only 2 activities in your activity stack.In case you would want atleast the last 3 detail pages then override back button and maintain a stack of 3 images to show the details page.